# Java JList not shown at JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I've got some bug in my parser, that parses site and sets 15 elements in a JList using `DefaultListModel`. Also I added timer, that refreshes for some time, clears this model, fills it again and then refreshes all the frame. So bug is in that, my list is shown for a random refresh ticks: model is still filled but list is not shown at the frame (`System.out.println(list.isVisible()`) shows TRUE, printing model I get all 15 of my items).

Some code:
this is in the frame class declaration.

```
private static DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
private static JList<String> list = new JList<>(listModel);

public static void execute() {
    //some code
    startTimer(activeProfile.getRefreshDelay() * 6000, activeProfile.getRefreshDelay() * 6000);
    show();
}

public static void fillEpisodes() {
    int i = 0;
    for (String entry : Episodes.getList()) {
        listModel.add(i, entry);
        i++;
    }
}
```

### TimerController class:

```
 public class TimerController extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainFrame.getListModel().clear();
        MainFrame.fillEpisodes();
        for(int i=0;i<MainFrame.getListModel().size();i++){
            System.out.println(MainFrame.getListModel().getElementAt(i));
        }
        MainFrame.show();
    }
}
```

Again, I want to mention that at the first startup my frame is shown perfectly, as it is even after first timer process. But after 2nd time timer processed my list contains 0, 15, 0,15 items.I tried to repaint list, to reset model, to repaint frame - no reaction.

Comment: Just to get this straight, at first the list is shown correct, and then it alternates between being empty and showing correctly?

Comment: @tobias_k yea, every second time it fills again. Maybe some problem with my listModel?

Comment: even System.out.println(list.getModel) shows me all the items for every timer tick

Comment: SOLVED: nedded to add one more listModel, fill it and then replace existing with it. Swing repaints list after model been changed, something like that :)